# Fraction dimensional "Euclidean" space

Tags: dimension-theory, hausdorff-dimension

The “dimension” of Euclidean space $\mathbb{E}^n$ can be explained as an algebraic property, simply as a dimension of a vector space over the field $\mathbb{R}$. It also can be understood as a Hausdorff dimension, using the Hausdorff measure defined via the euclidean distance. Each of these ways of defining “dimension” gives the same value: $n$, a natural number.

My question is not a rigorous one, rather a semi-justified, wondering type;
Are there any spaces, which could “deserve” to be called a fraction dimensional Euclidean space, as in, deserving the symbol $\mathbb{E}^s$ for some $s \ge 0$,  $s \notin \mathbb{N}$. The case when $s \notin \mathbb{Q}$ possibly being more "interesting”.

For example, one could say that the family: $\{ \{a, b\} \mid a, b \in \mathbb{R} \}$ with the Hausdorff metric is, in a sense, somewhat like $\mathbb{E}^{3/2}$. It seems to be between $\mathbb{E}$ ( $\mathbb{E}$ is a metric subspace of this space) and $\mathbb{E}^2$ (here more because of changing the "ordered pair” into “unordered pair”). One can also naturally ($(\lambda, \{ a, b \}, ) \mapsto \{ \lambda a, \lambda b\}$) define multiplication by a scalar on this space giving it a slight algebraic side. I'm not sure what its Hausdorff dimension is, so this $3/2$ dimension might be very wrong here...

Also, if there are such spaces, could there also be a way of transitioning between one such space to another, which would feel natural? In a sense that the family $\{ \mathbb{E}^t \mid t \ge 0 \}$ feels like a structured one, with some sort of order, much like the family $\{ \mathbb{E}^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$?

---

### EDIT:

To be a bit more precise, I think a good candidate for such a space would have a non-integer Hausdorff dimension with some algebraic (or, algebraic-like) structure. For example, allowing one to say that $\mathbb{E}^{1/2} \times \mathbb{E}^{1/2} \cong \mathbb{E}^1$ in a sense that some structure of $\mathbb{E}^1$ arises from the structure of the product.

Also, it would be interesting if on top of that, such a space would "look the same at every point". More concretely, for all $x, y \in \mathbb{E}^t$ there would exists $f \colon \mathbb{E}^t \to \mathbb{E}^t$ such that $f(x) = y$ and $f$ would preserve metric, measure and some other properties, if possible. (Much like translation does for the usual Euclidean $\mathbb{E}^n$ spaces).

---

### EDIT:

Thanks to the comments of Alfred Yenger and Matt F. I now know that the mentioned family: $\{ \{a, b\} \mid a, b \in \mathbb{R} \}$ with the Hausdorff metric wouldn't be a good candidate for $\mathbb{E}^{3/2}$ since it has a Hausdorff dimension of 2.

---

### EDIT:

As user142382 has pointed out in his answer, there is no topological space $\mathbb{E}^{1/2}$ such that $\mathbb{E}^{1/2} \times \mathbb{E}^{1/2} \cong \mathbb{E}^1$ if by symbol $\times$ one would mean the usual Cartesian product. Therefore, the meaning behind $\times$ could be loosened so that there would be some “solutions” and, hopefully, in the case of usual Euclidean spaces, $\times$ would reduce to the Cartesian product. For example, could a completion of Cartesian product be already enough to guarantee the existence of space $\mathbb{E}^{1/2}$ with the mentioned property?

Comment: Perhaps I completely misunderstand, but isn't the set of unordered pairs of $\mathbb{R}^2$ just $\mathbb{R}^2/\sim$, where the equivalence relation identifies $(a,b) \sim (b,a)$? If so, it's modeled by a half-space, namely, the half space cut out by the line $y = x$ and everything above/below. This has Hausdorff dimension 2, since it's a surface (with boundary).

Comment: but would this question arise, if the Linear Algebra dimension and the Geometric Measure theoretic dimension had two well distinguished terms in English?

Comment: @AlfredYerger, I wasn't really sure what could it be, and I'm not entirely sure whether the Hausdorff metric applied here could've changed the Hausdorff dimension. If the use of Hausdorff metric is not important here, then $3/2$ isn't that appropriate.

Comment: @PietroMajer Well... possibly, but I was wondering whether there could be some other spaces for which one could argue that for the somewhat algebraic, geometric measure theoretic, (and hopefully even more) reasons the dimension wouldn't be a natural number, but, at each of these viewpoints, this "dimension" would agree.

Comment: Since you need to give up the $\mathbb R$ linear structure, a cheap compromise definition of "$\mathbb E^{1/2}$" could also be a $\mathbb Q$ linear subspace of $\mathbb R$ which is maximal w.r.to the property $V\cap \sqrt{2}V=(0)$ (there is one by Zorn's lemma).  So $V$ and $\sqrt{2}V$ are isomorphic and $\mathbb{R}=V\oplus V'$ as $\mathbb Q$ linear subspaces. (but I guess any such V would be quite pathological from the point of view of measure)

Comment: Would fractals and their fractional dimension satisfy you as an answer ?

Comment: @KonstantinosKanakoglou I'm aware that many fractals have non-integer dimensions (in a sense of, for example, Hausdorff dimension). However, I was wondering whether there could be some spaces which not only have non-integer measure-theoretic dimension, but also some other properties, which could feel somewhat "Euclidean" like. For example, it would be interesting if one could think of $\mathbb{E}^1$ as a product $\mathbb{E}^{1/2} \times \mathbb{E}^{1/2}$ with some of its natural structure being somewhat "derived" from $\mathbb{E}^{1/2}$.

Comment: So you would like non-integer Haussdorff dim + some vector space structure on it .. Maybe this should be more explicitely stated in the OP.

Comment: @KonstantinosKanakoglou I edited the question. I wouldn't necessarily say that those are the “requirements”, though. Essentially, I wanted to know whether there are some spaces with a “nice enough” structure that someone could be convinced to call them Euclidean spaces. (And because of that, for example, place it in some hierarchy of Euclidean spaces with a non-integer dimension, allowing one to say that it is “in between” two usual Euclidean spaces).

Comment: We can write the Haussdorff distance between unordered pairs $\{a,b\}$ and $\{c,d\}$ as $$\max(|\!\max(a,b)-\max(c,d)|, |\!\min(a,b)-\min(c,d)|)$$ So we can add to the comment by @AlfredYerger that the space of unordered pairs is isomorphic to the half-space of $\mathbb{R}^2$ below the main diagonal, with the $\ell^\infty$ norm.

Comment: Given the conversation here, I’d say the original question has a fairly strong negative answer, and a weaker question would be good in a new post. One we could try is: Suppose $m$ Cantor sets and $n$ Sierpinski gaskets have the product $P$, with dimension $d=m\frac{\log 2}{\log 3} + n\frac{\log 3}{\log 2}$. Can we always find continuous injections $\mathbb{R}^{floor(d)} \hookrightarrow P \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{ceil(d)}$ whose composition has Hausdorff dimension $floor(d)$?

Answer (score 7):

One remark: there is no metric space $\mathbb{E}^{1/2}$ of Hausdorff dimension $\frac{1}{2}$ whose topological square $\mathbb{E}^{1/2} \times \mathbb{E}^{1/2}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{E}^1$, i.e., $\mathbb{R}$. A space of of Hausdorff dimension $\frac{1}{2}$ must necessarily be totally disconnected, so its square will be as well. So I guess you have some other notion of product in mind?

Comment: sorry, I meant this answer to be a comment but typed it in the wrong place.

Comment: There is no topological space $X$ such that $X^2\cong\mathbb R$. Since $\mathbb R$ is connected, so must be $X$, but then you can show so is $X^2$ minus any one of its points. But removing a point from $\mathbb R$ disconnects it.

Comment: To be honest, regarding that product, I mentioned it since it would be a very nice property to have as an argument to call some space $\mathbb{E}^{1/2}$. However, if there could be some way of altering that product to make this work, it still might be a good argument. For example, could taking a completion of a Cartesian product be enough to avoid the mentioned discconnectedness issue?